# Calculating this specific Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $s: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R,$ $$s(x, y) = (2x - y)^2 + (x - y)^2$$ and $f: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R,$ $$ f(x, y) = \begin{cases} 1 - s(x, y)^{\frac 1 2} & s(x, y) \leq 1 \\ 0 & s(x, y) \geq 1 \end{cases}$$

I am now supposed to calculate $\int_{\mathbb R^2}f \text d\lambda.$ I already have done some calculations and, if I did not make any mistake, know that I have to calculate: $$\int_{-\sqrt 5}^{\sqrt 5} \int_{\frac{3y - \sqrt{5 - y^2}}{5}}^{\frac{3y + \sqrt{5 - y^2}}{5}}\left(1 - \sqrt{(2x - y)^2 + (x - y)^2}\right)\text dx\text dy$$

But now I am stuck. Is there a helpful transformation that I don't see or is the approach itself not good?

Comment: Let $(u,v)=(2x-y,x-y)$. Compute the Jacobian then rewrite the integral. Afterwards use polar coordinates. You could do this in one transformation $(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta) = (2x-y,x-y)$ but I don't recommend it if you are new to this procedure. Jacobians chain in a convenient way anyway.

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it. By any chance, would $\frac \pi 3$ be the correct answer? I'm not too sure and I don't know any application to check with?

Comment: That's what I get. Good job!